# What does it mean when a word in a sentence is followed by (read another word)?

Tags: word-usage

Few days ago, I came across a [newspaper article](https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/lead/mplads-its-suspension-and-why-it-must-go/article31504548.ece). One particular sentence was like this:

> First, the scheme violates one of the cardinal principles, which though not specifically written down in the Constitution, actually permeates the entire Constitution: separation of powers. Simply put, this scheme, in effect, gives an executive function to legislators (read legislature).

What is the meaning of `legislators(read legislature)` or in general what is the usage of `word(read another-word)`?

Answer (score 1):

It means that you should interpret that word this way, literally "read that word as if it were *this*".

It is usually used in a sardonic or cynical way to add an opinion or a personal interpretation of something, for example:

> He is long-term unemployed (read: lazy).

In your example though, the difference between legislators and legislature is negligible and it seems that the writer has used this to explain a term or add an alternative term that may be more recognisable to the reader. A "legislator" is just someone who legislates; "legislature" is the proper term for the legislative body of a country or state. The writer appears to give both a generic, and a specific term for the same thing.

Comment: Thank you for the response. @Astralbee The first word, then as I believe is used for `formality` . Am I correct?

Comment: @TylerRake not really, if anything I'd say the word in brackets is the formal term. A "legislator" is just someone who legislates. "Legislature" is the proper term for the legislative body of a country or state.

Comment: It can be used for purposes of explanation of a point of view, as it is here.